# Reverting a submodule with Git

Tags: git, git-submodules

I did

```
git submodule add git://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim.git bundle/snipmate
```

and then I deleted the directory.  How do I revert it?  How do I revert files within it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could update the submodule:

```
git submodule update bundle/snipmate
```